# Differential equation soulotion exaplanation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am solving this differential equation:

$$ \frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{1}{Ax^2-Bx+C}$$

I know that I need to substitute like this : $A=k_1 B=k_1 (a+b+2c)+k_2$ and $C=k_1 (a+c)(b+c)$, and also that the answer is

$$x=(B-√(B^2-4AC) \tanh⁡(1/2 (K+t) √(B^2-4AC)))/2A$$

My problem is that I dont know how to see that substitution and that the answer will be a tanh function. Can someone please explain this for me.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Hi and welcome! Please, spend a few minutes to learn the basics of MathJAX to properly type your question: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference, so we will be able to provide a more accurate answer. Thanks!

Comment: what is $K$? {}{

Answer (score 0):

the solution has the form
$$
t = \int \frac{dx}{Ax^2 + Bx+C}
$$
Now compute the integral: let us assume that
$$
Ax^2+Bx+C =
A(-(x-\alpha)^2 + \beta^2), \beta>0
$$

then:
$$
At = \int \frac{dx}{-(x-\alpha)^2 + \beta^2}
= \frac 1\beta \text{atanh} \frac{x-\alpha}{\beta} +C
\\
x(t) = \alpha + \beta\tanh(\beta(At-C))
$$